# Mostrar un mapa por cada iteración - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy mostrando registros de mi base de datos iterandolos, en cada uno de ellos quiero mostrar un mapa, pero solo consigo que cargue uno, incluso diferenciandolos por cada iteración que hace el `foreach`.

```
@foreach ($locales as $item)
   <div id="mapaPropiedad_{{$item->id}}" class="mapaPropiedad"></div>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address_{{$item->id}}">

    <script>
                                
    var idLocal = "{{$item->id}}";
    console.log(idLocal);

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initMap() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.4078968, -0.4317228);
      var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 18,
         center: latlng,
         mapId: '6d7bc70ff139bf71',
         disableDefaultUI: true,
         scrollwheel: false,
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaPropiedad_'+ idLocal +''), mapOptions);
      codeAddress()
    }

    function codeAddress() {
     var address = document.getElementById('address_'+ idLocal +'').value;
     console.log(address);
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == 'OK') {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: results[0].geometry.location
       });
       } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
       }
      });
    }
    </script>
@endforeach
```

No se si es una buena practica meter dentro del foreach el script pero no se hacerlo de otro modo, pero solo me está mostrando el segundo mapa.

El `console.log(address);` me devuelve todo el rato la misma diracción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cada iteración del ciclo estás sobrescribiendo las variables y funciones Javascript y lo notarías en la consola si en lugar de declarar las variables con `var` lo haces con `let`. La opción sería usar una función que reciba los parámetros necesarios y  crear cada mapa:

```
<script>
// Solo estás recibiendo una variable
// De ser necesario, agrega otras, como latitud y longitud
function creaMapa(idLocal) {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.4078968, -0.4317228);
    let mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: latlng,
        mapId: '6d7bc70ff139bf71', // ¿Este puede ser igual siempre?
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
    }
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapaPropiedad_'+ idLocal +''), mapOptions);
    // Envía los parámetros necesarios a la función
    codeAddress(idLocal, map, geocoder);
}
function codeAddress(idLocal, map, geocoder) {
     let address = document.getElementById('address_'+ idLocal +'').value;
     console.log(address);
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == 'OK') {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: results[0].geometry.location
       });
       } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
       }
      });
    }

</script>
```

Después, en el ciclo PHP ejecutas la función para crear los mapas

```
@foreach ($locales as $item)
   <div id="mapaPropiedad_{{$item->id}}" class="mapaPropiedad"></div>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address_{{$item->id}}">

    <script>
    // Ejecuta la función
    creaMapa("{{$item->id}}");
    </script>
@endforeach
```

### Edición para optimizar y evitar errores

Creo que una mejor opción sería crear un arreglo de IDs y crear los mapas después de que se haya cargado el DOM:

```
// Definir arreglo
@php
$mapIds = [];
@endphp
@foreach ($locales as $item)
   <div id="mapaPropiedad_{{$item->id}}" class="mapaPropiedad"></div>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ $item->direccion }} {{ $item->municipio }} {{ $item->provincia }}" id="address_{{$item->id}}">
    @php
    // Insertar ID en arreglo:
    $mapIds[] = $item->id;
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

Al final del ciclo, recorre los IDs para crear los mapas:

```
<script>
// Crear arreglo Javascript
let mapIds = {{json_encode($mapIds)}};
// Crea los mapas hasta haber cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    mapIds.forEach(mapId => creaMapa(mapId));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @Triby un placer saludarte de nuevo! Lo que pasa que de este modo me dice `creaMapa is not defined` supongo que no esta declarada

Comment: @Miguel, solo pon el script con las funciones antes del ciclo.

Comment: Lo he probado pero me dice lo mismo, me da error que no existe la función aquí  `creaMapa("{{$item->id}}");` @Triby

Comment: @Miguel, revisa si hay más errores en la consola, si algo está fallando, la función no podrá crearse. También edita la pregunta para mostrar el código actualizado.

Comment: Lo que me dice también es que `initMap` tampoco esta definida

Comment: @Miguel, eliminé esa función porque en la pregunta no se ve donde la usas.

Comment: Si no ponia lo de `initMap` no me funcionaba el mapa @Triby ,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132674/discussion-between-triby-and-miguel).